# how to assign vectors from loops in a list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a loop that results in 5 vectors of different sizes, I would like to know how to assign these vectors in a one list.

A minimal example of what I'm trying to do, and where I'm going wrong would be:

```
    m=5;n=10
    sh=c(0,0,0,0,-39,-75,-12,11,-15)
    th=c(0,0,0,0,-19,-86,-74,-53,-41)
    Cj=c(-9,-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,6,6,9)
    for(k in  m:n-1){
    Ai=vector("numeric", k)
    for(i in 1:k){  
    Ai[i]=exp(sh[k]+Cj[i]*th[k])/(1+exp(sh[k]+Cj[i]*th[k]))^2
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 2
a3 <- 3

xy <- ls(pattern = "a")

fl <- list()

for (i in seq_along(xy)) {
  fl[i] <- get(xy[i])
}

names(fl) <- xy

$a1
[1] 1
$a2
[1] 2
$a3
[1] 3
```

Or, for the fun of it, you can use `mget`:

```
> mget(xy)
$a1
[1] 1

$a2
[1] 2

$a3
[1] 3
```